# Meaning of Strong Primitivity

Tags: finite-groups

As J.D.Dixon noted in his great book; *Permutations Group*, we can speak about *Strong Primitivity* of a group acting on a set $\Omega$ by means of orbital graphs. The way he paved employes digraphs prove if such a group is strong primitive or not. I referred to another reference came from P.J.Cameron *(Toplogy in permutation groups*) to find additional information. He cited that Wielandt observed that primitivity is not strong enough. Cameron continues by illustrating an example:

> Let $G$ is a primitive group on a finite set $\Omega$ and let $\Delta$ be a non-empty proper subset of $\Omega$. then the following seperation property holds: for any distinct $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in$ $\Omega$, there exists $g\in G$ with $\alpha^g$ $\in \Delta$ and $\beta^g$ $\notin \Delta$. This fails for infinite primitive groups.

and that is why Wielandt proposed the property of Strong Primitivity. Honestly, I didn't get much of what Cameron noted and need someone to elaborate. Why such a condition's named separate property? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest $G$-invariant topology in $\Omega$ containing $\Delta$ is the topology generated by the translated sets $\Delta^g$ for all $g\in G$. Its basis consists of finite intersections of such sets. A point $\alpha$ in $\Omega$ has a neighborhood not containing a point $\beta$ if and only if $\alpha\in\Delta^g$ but $\beta\not\in\Delta^g$ for some $g\in G$. The existence of such a neighborhood for each pair $(\alpha,\beta)$ of distinct points of $\Omega$ is the *separation property* T1 of topology. The weaker property T0 means that this only holds for either $(\alpha,\beta)$ or $(\beta,\alpha)$ but not necessarily for both pairs.